# compositor replace part of an image

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, masking

I am trying to replace the sky of an image with another image in the blender 3d compositor. I selected the sky with a mask and I also combined then but I still see some parts of the original image so how can I remove that?? I tried changing the mix nodes values but that did not make any sense so can somebody help me out?

(so the clouds should be removed)
[image]

Comment: You forgot to pack the images in your blend...

Comment: Why not use a simple mix node (instead of darken and add) with the mask driving the factor input of the mix?

Comment: @3pointedit Thanks, that worked. This is indeed lot easier than working with that strange dark, add ect options.